# How to config for all requests for doing something before fetching api by react-query

Tags: reactjs, tanstackreact-query

I fetch api by react-query, but I have to do something before every requests. So how do I config? Thank you for reading!

I expect that I can do something like this or whatever as long as it can help to resolve my problem:

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    // config something here to do something before every request
});
```

I create a custom hook for useQuery:

```
import {
  QueryFunctionContext,
  QueryKey,
  UseQueryOptions,
  useQuery,
} from "react-query";

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-anonymous-default-export
export default (props: UseQueryOptions) => {
  const { queryFn, ...rest } = props;
  const query = useQuery({
    ...rest,
    queryFn: (params: QueryFunctionContext<QueryKey, any>) => {
      // do something before call api
      console.log("do something before call api");

      //  call api
      queryFn && queryFn(params);
    },
  });

  return query;
};
```

Are there any better ways to do this?

Comment: Just readout the documents: https://tanstack.com/query/v3/docs/react/quick-start